# Running javascript in the Google Chrome extension after a page has done loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The website I'm targeting is pretty much a Javascript application. So I need to add HTML after everything has completed loading. I tried using MutationObserver, but it still tries to execute javascript too early and I get the following error code `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

My code

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test Description",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at" : "document_idle",
    "matches": ["https://pastvu.com/p/*"]
  }]

}
```

**content.js**

```
new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    addHtml();
    observer.disconnect();
}).observe(document.querySelector('body'), {childList: true});


function addHtml(){

    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("class","tltp-wrap");

    var newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.com');

    var linkButton = document.createElement('span');
    linkButton.setAttribute('class','glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker');

    newLink.appendChild(linkButton);
    newDiv.appendChild(newLink);

    document.getElementsByClassName("toolsBtm")[0].appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

[Here is the](https://pastvu.com/p/577385) page I'm targeting. As you can see the `<body>` looks like this

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/module/appMain.js?__=wfDkO"></script>
</body>
```

My goal is to wait until the body html loads or at least unitil `.toolsBtm` div is present.

I changed `content.js` to this and still no luck

```
new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    var bodyLoaded = document.getElementsByClassName('toolsBtm');
    if (bodyLoaded.length > 0) {
        alert('a');
        addHtml();
    }
}).observe(document.querySelector('body'), {childList: true});


function addHtml(){

    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("class","tltp-wrap");

    var newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.setAttribute('href','http://www.google.com');

    var linkButton = document.createElement('span');
    linkButton.setAttribute('class','glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker');

    newLink.appendChild(linkButton);
    newDiv.appendChild(newLink);

    document.getElementsByClassName("toolsBtm")[0].appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `"run_at" : "document_end"` ?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen `document_end` is no later than `document_idle`.

Comment: @FiriceNguyen yes, I did

Comment: John, your observer doesn't really make sense; it doesn't wait for anything specific, it just triggers on first-ever-observed DOM modification. You should somehow filter for an event you want.

Comment: @Xan as I understand my observer is waiting for the `<body>` content to change

Comment: True; you don't have `subtree` set, so it should only be immediate children. However, practice shows that's not specific enough. It's hard to suggest changes without digging into the web app itself. What is the exact event you're trying to capture.

Comment: @Xan The page is https://pastvu.com/p/577385 I'm trying to append an html code to a `div`, however the entire body is loaded via javascript.

Comment: There's no way for us to give detailed suggestions, other than that you need to wait for the element you need to exist. However, that should be something you already understand. Questions require that enough information be *in the question* in order for them to be answerable. Just a link to the page is insufficient (But, in this case it's helpful). At an absolute minimum, you need to include enough of the page HTML for us to see what you're attempting to modify. It would also be helpful to know how the in-page JavaScript is determining what to add, as other possible solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

In our plugin we have something like

```
export function invokeAfterDomIsReady(context = document, selector, time = 400, func) {
    const domEl = context.querySelector(selector);
    if (domEl != null) {
        func(domEl);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            invokeAfterDomIsReady(context, selector, time, func);
        }, time);
    }
}
```

It is something what usually used during ui testing with Selenium.